# PDF library for Android, iOS, and web

Tags: android, library, ios, pdf-viewer

I am looking for a **PDF library that can support Android, iOS, and web** (as a nice-to-have). The library would be integrated into a platform with hundreds of thousands of users.

The only required features are:

- PDF viewing (**lazy-loaded** pages)
- Basic controls, like jump to page, next-previous page, zoom, etc.
- Text search
- 360-degree rotation
- Geometrical annotations (e.g. rectangle or oval marking in a
  document)

**What I've looked into so far:**

- [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) - nice but expensive
- [PDFTron](https://apryse.com/) - also premium
- [RadaeePDF](https://www.radaeepdf.com/home/technical-specification) - less known and cheaper (= riskier?)
- [Foxit Reader Mobile SDK](https://developers.foxit.com/products/pdf-sdk/) - premium
- [Debenu](https://www.debenu.com/blog/debenu-quick-pdf-library-11-15-released.html) - premium

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone have good experience with any of the products above?
2. Do you know other products that check the requirements I mentioned,
   support Android, iOS, and web? Premium or free.

Answer (score 1):

The LEADTOOLS PDF SDK (https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/pdf) can be used to implement the features you listed, such as loading and viewing PDF documents, text search, annotations, along with other features. The toolkit is available for Android, iOS, and JavaScript. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of this toolkit’s vendor)

This is a commercial toolkit but a free evaluation is available for download from the website:
https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main

Free technical support is available throughout the evaluation as well through email and online chat, should it be needed:
https://www.leadtools.com/support/supportoptions

Comment: Please describe (in technical details) how it does lazy-loading, as it is a required feature. Also, does it do rotation?